# Getting the error "Expected expression before ')' token" for a headerfile that shouldn't need any changes

Tags: c, freertos, unexpected-token

Like the title says, I just knew this file "portmacro.h" (is for use with freeRTOS microprocessors) needed to be included and after attempting to compile after including the file I am getting the error "Expected expression before ')' token" for the following two sections of code. If it isn't something quick and clearly mistyped then I assume something I am doing elsewhere in the program is somehow causing this issue. Any help/guidance will be appreciated.

Exact Error messages:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\JHprojs\helloTimersFreeRTOS\Library\Include/portmacro.h: In function 'vPortRaiseBASEPRI':
C:\Users\user\Documents\JHprojs\helloTimersFreeRTOS\Library\Include/portmacro.h:202:69: error: expected expression before ')' token
   :"=r" (ulNewBASEPRI) : "i" ( configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY ) : "memory"
                                                                     ^
C:\Users\user\Documents\JHprojs\helloTimersFreeRTOS\Library\Include/portmacro.h: In function 'ulPortRaiseBASEPRI':
C:\Users\user\Documents\JHprojs\helloTimersFreeRTOS\Library\Include/portmacro.h:219:95: error: expected expression before ')' token
   :"=r" (ulOriginalBASEPRI), "=r" (ulNewBASEPRI) : "i" ( configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY ) : "memory"
                                                                                               ^
make: *** [User/main.o] Error 1
```

and

```
expected expression before ')' token 
   portmacro.h/helloTimersFreeRTOS/Library/Include  line 219    C/C++ Problem
```

The two sections of code from "portmacro.h"

```
portFORCE_INLINE static uint32_t ulPortRaiseBASEPRI( void )
{
uint32_t ulOriginalBASEPRI, ulNewBASEPRI;

    __asm volatile
    (
        "   mrs %0, basepri                                         \n" \
        "   mov %1, %2                                              \n" \
        "   msr basepri, %1                                         \n" \
        "   isb                                                     \n" \
        "   dsb                                                     \n" \
        :"=r" (ulOriginalBASEPRI), "=r" (ulNewBASEPRI) : "i" ( configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY ) : "memory"
    ); 
}
```

and

```
portFORCE_INLINE static void vPortRaiseBASEPRI( void )
{
uint32_t ulNewBASEPRI;

    __asm volatile
    (
        "   mov %0, %1                                              \n" \
        "   msr basepri, %0                                         \n" \
        "   isb                                                     \n" \
        "   dsb                                                     \n" \
        :"=r" (ulNewBASEPRI) : "i" ( configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY ) : "memory"
    );
}
```

The spot it specifically is taking issue with is `:"=r" (ulOriginalBASEPRI), "=r" (ulNewBASEPRI) : "i" ( configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY ) : "memory"`

vscode even more specifically pins the issue [to this exact spot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsqD9.png).

Here is an image of the error message exactly from within eclipse.[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Heh3.png)

Comment: I tried putting a ')' in a few places like vscode suggests, but I am unfamiliar with inline assembly and assume whoever made this header knows what they are doing when it comes to syntax here.

Comment: `after attempting to compile after including the file` Please post all _the exact_ error and warning messages you are getting from your compiler. Please post an [MCVE]. How did you include the file? Please include compiler, compiler version and compiler options you are using to compile.

Comment: First I want to make it clear that IF the solution isn't a quick fix for the problematic line(s) I specified, I don't expect someone to dive in and check all the other possible things that could be causing this issue, that's too much to expect. Is there not a proper way here to just ask for a quick check of the syntax and then otherwise I'll be diving in more to the rest of what is a massive program with many many includes? Also compiler is the 'Cross ARM GCC' version '9.2.1', compiler options:(Looking into this right now)

Comment: `for a quick check of the syntax` Well, if you want it that way, the functions look unmodified to what is [in freertos upstream](https://github.com/Duet3D/FreeRTOS/blob/master/src/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4_MPU/portmacro.h#L240). So it should work with gcc compiler for cortex-m4. @edit You did copy the eclipse intepretation of errors. Go to "Console" tab and copy the text vebatim.

Comment: My bad, I have edited it to have the console message. @edit I believe I need to look into the config file because that expression may not be defined yet, -> configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY.       Sometimes getting this all spelled out on here is what allows you to see where you need to look, I appreciate you spending any time here thus far.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is as dumb as me in the future and may be overlooking the same thing as me, the expression

```
configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY
```

from the line

`:"=r" (ulOriginalBASEPRI), "=r" (ulNewBASEPRI) : "i" ( configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY ) : "memory"`

was there, but not defined in the freeRTOSConfig header file. So obviously it needed defined and this fixed all build issues.